# Mysterious Valentine's Riddle

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme

*The rules of this puzzle are unstated

You must guess them and find how they're slated

If you're here then you're pro'lly not dated

If it's today then it isn't belated*

*It's ok cause I know that you're fated

You're destined to be loved and not hated

Don't worry, it's not overrated

You'll find it I'm sure if you've waited*

---

*Green stood up with a start

Blue was all over the chart

White couldn't stand to be art

Red wasn't ever apart*

*Purple was afraid and a tart

Pink was around and a heart

Orange jumped over the cart

Violet will never depart*

---

*Enjoy the puzzle I created

Solve this which I've fabricated

If you solve this then you've graduated

I hope that you're rejuvenated*

Comment: But mr green has been killed.... oh wait wrong riddle :P

Comment: @OmegaKrypton ***HINT:** The answer(s) may be of or relating to the physical or observable world.***

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a poem about

> Sunset

Green stood up with a start

> Trees / Plants

Blue was all over the chart

> The blue sky

White couldn't stand to be art

> The clouds

Red wasn't ever apart

Purple was afraid and a tart

Pink was around and a heart

Orange jumped over the cart

Violet will never depart

> The colors of the sunset

Comment: The whole answer(s) is/are not *sunset* but you got part of it (plants - grass actually)